# php set default text for optional value in form after user registration?

Tags: php, javascript, html

How can I set a default value such as "don't have any information" instead of a blank in front end part using php or any means for optional field which not require user to fill in(full name, dob, address....) after they register on my page for future user's adjustment. Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user leaves a field blank, the variable you receive in $_POST will be an empty string. So on the receiving page:

```
if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
else {
    $name = "did not submit a name";
}
// then insert $name and your other form variables into your database...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="don't have info" />
```

this will remove "don't have info" on click on text box

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $doError='placeholder="don\'t have info"'; 
}
?>

<input type="text" <?php echo @$doError; ?> name="email" />
```

Comment: Note that this is HTML5 only.

Comment: Oh, sweet! I was just explaining the primitive javascript version of this behavior in another comment. Nice to know this exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `value` in your html:

```
<input type="text" value="don't have info" />
```

Comment: To clarify, this will cause the input field that the user sees to have the text "don't have info" in it by default. They can then delete it and type in their own info if they want to. The answer I posted assumes that the field was blank and the user left it blank; it lets you put a default value into your database for when the name is displayed later. So it depends on which you want to happen!

Comment: A helpful trick is to use javascript's onFocus to blank the box as soon as the user clicks on (or otherwise navigates to) it. That way they don't have to manually highlight and delete the default text.